# problema con google play al generar pruebas internas - queda en lista para enviar a revisión

Tags: android, ionic, google-play-console

Ya estando en la google play console habiendo subido el bundle, eh tenido que resubirlas por correcciones de recursos gráficos y detalles menores, veo que la ultima versión **"disponible para testers internos"** no es la que tendría que ser.

volví a resubir la que se encuentra en **"Lista para enviar a revisión"** y no cambia el estado.

La que se encuentra en disponible para testers internos la subí yo, y quedo como debería, pero las 2 siguientes correcciones no cambiaron su estado, y como dije los cambios fueron de recursos gráficos y detalles menores.

ya revise desde el celular la ultima versión disponible de la aplicación y coincide con la ultima 10 nov, y debería tener fecha de hoy 22 de dic.

Tampoco da señales de presentar algún error que bloquee su subida, si se necesita mas  información o pasaron pro algo similar ayudaría su comentario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a tu comentario:

> volví a resubir la que se encuentra en "Lista para enviar a revisión"
> y no cambia el estado.

El Android App Bundle que subes y que deseas sobre escriba a otro debes asegurarte que sea subido en el "track" correspondiente  ya sea alpha, beta o producción.

> ya revise desde el celular la ultima versión disponible de la
> aplicación y coincide con la ultima 10 nov, y debería tener fecha de
> hoy 22 de dic.

Si no presento problemas al subir el .AAB no te preocupes tarda algunas horas en mostrarse para descargar desde Google Play, pero debes asegurar 2 cosas:

1 Que la liberación sea al 100% de los usuarios.

2 En el caso de un .AAB de una app de producción esta debe ser aprobada y posteriormente tienes que esperar a que se replique en los servidores de Google para que este disponible.

Un tip importante para que obtengas la nueva versión lo más rápido posible es que elimines el caché de tu aplicación Google Play, de esta forma podrás ver la versión que esperas mucho más rápido.